# I'm trying to write a code for counter using vhdl

Tags: vhdl, counter

this is the VHDL code for synchronous type counter. As I'm still new in vhdl, I'm having problem in writing the testbench to simulate this code. can anyone give me some suggestions on how to write the testbench? thank you

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity cnt4 is
    port( CLK, RST  : in std_logic;
          Q         : out std_logic);
end cnt4;

architecture EX1 of cnt4 is
signal cnt : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);

begin
    process(CLK, RST)
    begin
        if RST = '1' then
            cnt <= "00";
        elsif CLK'event and CLK = '1' then
            if cnt = 3 then
                cnt <= "00";
                Q <= '1';
            else
                cnt <= cnt + 1;
                Q <= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end EX1;
```

---

this is the testbench that i've tried to write so far

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity TESTBENCH is 
end TESTBENCH;

architecture EX1 of TESTBENCH is
    signal CLK, RST : std_logic;
    signal Q        : std_logic;

    component cnt4
        port( CLK, RST : in std_logic;
              Q        : out std_logic );
    end component;

begin
    U0: cnt4 port map(CLK, RST, Q);

    process
    begin
        CLK <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        CLK <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        wait;
    end process;

    process
    begin
        RST <= '0'; wait for 10 ns;
        RST <= '1'; wait for 10 ns;

        wait;
    end process;
end EX1;
```

the simulation result using the testbench above is as in the picture

[simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el1ze.jpg)

it may look ridiculous as I don't really know how to write the testbench. would be glad if anyone can help me

Comment: You want more than 4 CLK cycles after reset goes invalid allowing Q to go valid then invalid again. Also your first assignment to '1' on CLK will be accepted by the condition `CLK'event and CLK = '1`, consider using `rising_edge(CLK)` or an initial value of `'0'` for `CLK`. In the search bar **[vhdl] counter testbench**, you'll find examples of testbenches made functional and their common problems. What actual problem have you encountered?

Comment: actually i'm a student and i'm trying to answer the question in the exercise book by myself. the question is to write the testbench code for the given vhdl code. so, i'm assuming the vhdl code is already correct. i edit my question and put the simulation using the testbench i wrote above in the question. as you can see, the RST's value is constantly at 1 after going 0 for just one time. so, how should i write the testbench to fix this?

Comment: Your testbench only does this: [testbench.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CqWTY.png). Would you like to update either your testbench code or the waveform so they match? You've obviously generated more than one clock in the edited in simulation waveform link.  `RST <= '1'; wait for 10 ns;  -- WAS '0'` and `RST <= '0'; wait for 10 ns;  -- was '1'` in the testbench. You simply have the polarity wrong, it's high true. Move the assignment to Q to a concurrent statement, it's a clocked flip flop where it's assigned.

Comment: i'm sorry i think the waveform that i gave is wrong and it's definitely should be as you shown. is there any suggestion on how to write the testbench? i really don't know how to do it

Comment: Your testbench only simulates one clock cycle. In process assigning CLK encapsulate the final wait in an if statement with a condition: `if Now > 120 ns then wait; end if;`  The function NOW returns the current simulation time. This tells you to stop after 120 ns. This should give you something like:  [cnt4_testbench_120_ns.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MB96T.png) (I favor a different clock generator). A process with a wait without an argument will never resume. The if statement does that after 120 ns instead of immediately. Note the reset polarity has been reversed. CLK drives the model.

Comment: can you show me how you write the testbench? because i've been wondering how to create the cnt in the simulation like you showed

Comment: Believe it or not my last two comments contain every change to your testbench to create the second waveform with your original cnt4 entity/architecture.